# Submit form when Clicking "Enter" button, with validation

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have  a form , I need to submit the form when "enter" key Pressed, I have given the button type as "submit" , so that the form is submitted when enter pressed, at the same time ,i am calling a function with validation and confirmation, it not asking for the confirmation message and closed and submitted, My expected result is , when i press enter it should show the confirmation/Validation msg and I press enter again it should submit. Below is my code

```
            <form name="form1" id="form1" action="SizeMaster.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtSizeName"  value="" />
             <button type="submit" onClick="return fnSave()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">save</i><span>SAVE</span></button>
             </form>


              function fnSave(){
              if(form1.txtSizeName.value==""){
                alert("Please Enter size");
                return false;
              }
                  (!confirm("Are You Sure Want to confirm the Request?")){
              return false;
              }
              form1.action="SizeMaster.php?Mode=SAVE";
 }
```

Comment: ChangeonClick to onsubmit (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

Comment: What have you tried to debug your problem? Is there any handler registered for `onSubmit`? The code only shows a handler for an `onClick` event for the button, which is obviously not triggered when you do not click on that button

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form#form1", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
//put your conditions here
if(form1.txtSizeName.value==""){
     alert("Please Enter size");
      return false;
    }
});

//OR


$(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('form#form1').submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call your function on onClick event. And you have a missing `if` before confirm.

Try this.

```
 <form
  name="form1"
  id="form1"
  onSubmit="return fnSave()"
  action="SizeMaster.php"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  method="post"
>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtSizeName" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect">
    <i class="material-icons">save</i><span>SAVE</span>
  </button>
</form>

<script>
  function fnSave() {
    if (form1.txtSizeName.value == "") {
      alert("Please Enter size");
      return false;
    }
    if (!confirm("Are You Sure Want to confirm the Request?")) {
      return false;
    }
    form1.action = "SizeMaster.php?Mode=SAVE";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of `onsubmit`

```
<form onsubmit="return fnSave()" name="form1" id="form1" action="SizeMaster.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtSizeName" value="" /> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">save</i><span>SAVE</span></button> 
</form>
```

Comment: One should better use proper JS handlers nowadays instead of mixing that up in the markup

Comment: The SO asked why the function does not behave as expected not for best practice.

Answer (score -1):

you should add the action listener on the form element's onSubmit attribute

```
<from onSubmit='fnSave()' > ...
```

then on the `fnSave()` function you will get the event object on the `this` variable. then call this.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting. after that you can do your validation and other action

Comment: One should better use proper JS handlers nowadays instead of mixing that up in the markup